# How to submit comments in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, comments, submit

I want to submit a comment in main page then redirect to this page.
This is my action:

```
public function submitcommentAction(Request $request)
{
    $user=$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
       $uid=$user->getId();

    $comment=new comment();

    //$comment->setCafe();

    $form=$this->createFormBuilder($comment)
            ->add('cafe','hidden')
            ->add('description','textarea')
            ->getForm();
    if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $comment->setCafe($form['cafe']->getData());
            $comment->setUser($uid);
            $comment->setDescription($form['description']->getData());
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();
              // return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('showcofe'));   
            var_dump($em);
    exit();

        }
    }

                    $r='error';
        return $this->      render('CafeManagementBundle:Default:simple.html.twig',array('r'=>$r));

}
```

and this is my twig:

```
    <div class="new-comment">
      <div class="new-comment-text"> :your comment
        <div>
          <form id="comment-form" method="post" action={{path('subcomment')}}" {{form_enctype(form1)}}">
            <ul class="smallbuttons">

                <input type="hidden" id="form_cafe" name="form[cafe]" value="{{cafe.id}}" />
                  {{form_widget(form1.description)}}
                <div style="display:none">{{ form_rest(form1) }}</div>

         <p><a id="clickbotton1"     href="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit()" class="btn_smallorange edit2">submit</a></p> 
            </ul>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to pass hidden field(cafe) to controller. Plus would you please tell me, whether my controller is correct?

Comment: You are doing regular PHP in Symfony2. There is a lot of errors in your code. First, your Comment object should be hydrated with the request data by the Form itself (that's it job!). For the Cafe var, maybe it can be set from the URI? 

You should take a look at the documentation, there is a lot of examples: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html

Comment: Then it appears you are not submitting your form in a right way.
Your form HTML id is "comment-form" and you are trying to submit the "form1" with your javascript anchor. document.getElementById('form1').submit()) should be replaced by document.getElementById('comment-form').submit().

But why don't you just add a submit button instead of this link ?

Comment: I don't want to use cafe-id in url. I used hidden option in my action but it dosen't helpful :(

Comment: I'll test it Flo-Schield-Boddy. thanks